# AngularJS: [$injector:nomod] Module 'uiRouter' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to use `angular-ui-router` in my app, but am having issues when importing it

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiRouter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'uiRouter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here is my `main.js`

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

(function() {
    function config($locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

    }
    angular
        .module('myApp', ['uiRouter'])
        .config(config);

})();
```

My `index.html` file has the app declared
`<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">`
I've installed both packages via npm

```
myApp@1.0.0 /Users/.../myApp
├── angular@1.6.5
├─┬ angular-ui-router@1.0.3
│ └── @uirouter/core@5.0.3
```

Don't know if it's relevant but also declared it in `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.5",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.3",
```

In the past I've always imported angular libraries via `<script>` tags in `index.html` so am unfamiliar with importing as packages.

Also, I was reading that `ui-router` is being offered as scoped packages: https://ui-router.github.io/blog/uirouter-scoped-packages/ but don't know if it's relevant here (I also imported the packages described in this link but didn't seem to help).

**Question** Why isn't `angular-ui-router` being recognized?

Comment: could you provide a plunker of your code. And are you sure angular-ui-router is included

Comment: did you included the `angular-ui-router` inside your html with `script` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this to work but it wasn't what I initially expected.

I changed `main.js` to read

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

(function() {
    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        /* $locationProvider  //ignore
            .html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        }); */

    }
    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config);

})();
```

To explain: here I'm using both the ES6 import feature and as well an Angular dependency injection. I am importing via uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router' so that main.js can access this ui router object. Then I use ui.router in the Angular dependency injection since this is the internal name for the ui router in Angular. The provider names are also different for ngRoute and ui-router (`$locationProvider` in original code vs. `$urlRouterProvider` here).

I don't use a `<script>` tag at all to import an Angular library.